# jest.mock doesn't work when called inside a function

Tags: javascript, jestjs, mocking, ts-jest, babel-jest

**The setup:**

I have module that I want to mock in my tests, so I write this:

```
jest.mock('path/to/module, () => mocked_value);
```

in the top of my test file and it works fine.

**The problem:**

I want to use the same mock (`mocked_value` is a somewhat large object, and there are multiple modules being mocked) in multiple tests, but I cannot put the `jest.mock` calls into a separate function in a separate file, because then it doesn't work.

I have tried [`doMock`](https://jestjs.io/docs/jest-object#jestdomockmodulename-factory-options) instead, but is also doesn't work. The test is in TypeScript if it is relevant.

**Edit:**

`doMock` *should* work for this purpose, but it doesn't work for me at all. Even when I put `doMock` directly into the test file (where `mock` was working just fine), it doesn't work. Putting it directly into the test function doesn't work either.

**Environment:**

- OS: Windows 10
- Editor: VS Code
- Terminal: Git Bash
- Typescript: 4.4.4
- Node: v17.0.1
- (jest config) testEnvironment: jsdom
- (jest config) resolver: jest-pnp-resolver
- (jest config) transform: babel-jest:

Comment: If `jest.mock` isn't at the top level of the actual test file, it doesn't get hoisted, it doesn't run before the actual imports.

Comment: Ok, so why doesn't `jest.doMock` work either? Further testing reveled that `doMock` doesn't work even when put directly into the file or directly into the test.